# Flutter Riverpod: StateNotifier not rerendering widget

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a simple StateNotifier class like so:

```
class MyClass extends StateNotifier<Map<String, dynamic>> {
  Map<String, dynamic> data;

  MyClass({this.data}) : super(null) {
    data = data ?? {};
  }

  setData(Map<String, dynamic> newData) {
    data = {...data, ...newData};
  }
}
```

I have my provider defined in a providers.dart file:

```
final myClassProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => _myClass);
```

...which I'm importing and trying to "read" inside `build` of my widget and have the widget update when the state of MyClass changes:

```
MyClass _myClass = ref.watch(myClassProvider.notifier);
```

I have a couple of buttons which calls the `setData` method and I can see that it get's the new data, but my widget never rerenders. If I navigate back a screen and then forward again to the same view, I can see that it has been updated with the new data, but my widget never rerenders as it happens. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StateNotifier` has its own `state`.

```
class MyClass extends StateNotifier<Map<String, dynamic>> {

  MyClass(Map<String, dynamic> data) : super(data);

  setData(Map<String, dynamic> newData) {
    state = {...state, ...newData};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can fetch data from Map using Riverpod like this:-

```
  final dataValue = ref.watch(counterProvider);
    String name = dataValue['name'].toString();
    String email = dataValue['email'].toString();
    String address = dataValue['address'].toString();
```

and set these values on different text.

and We should pass and set the values in Map<String,dynamic> like this:-

```
final counterProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<Counter, Map<String, dynamic>>((_) => Counter());

class Counter extends StateNotifier<Map<String, dynamic>> {
  // Counter(Map<String, dynamic> data): super(data);
  Counter() : super({});

  void displayFile(String name, String email, String address) {
    Map<String, dynamic> cartMap = {"name": name, "email": email, "address": address};

    state = {...state, ...cartMap};
  }
}
```